# Quadratic optimisation to compute a transformation matrix

Tags: matlab, optimization, matrix

I have two 3D meshes and on these meshes exists points that are mapped to each other and points with no mapping. For these points I want to calculate a mapping.

I want to do this by calculating a transformation Matrix for each point of one mesh that is already mapped to a point in the other mesh. Afterwards I want to calculate with an quadratic optimization the best possible mapping for all other points.

f(p) = T_i * p

(I'm using homogeneous coordinates - so every transfomation matrix should look like this:

```
1 0 0 a_i
0 1 0 b_i
0 0 1 c_i
0 0 0   1
```

Because of some not existing mathematics knowledge I stuck at this point, could somebody tell what exactly I need to feed matlab with that it gives me back an optimized transformation matrix, preferably with a quadratic optimization.

(and maybe an elegant way to do the transformation matrix calculation - actually I do it with a loop that runs over all points and calcs line by line the a_i, b_i, c_i and transforms them to a new matrix..., is there a function in matlab?)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is very unclear what you are asking. Are you looking for the optimal translation of 3D points?

Comment: Exactly that's what I am looking for. I want to find a optimal translation matrix based on already mapped points (feature points) for all points that have no mapping yet.

Comment: this is still not clear. what does it mean "based on already mapped points"? If you have mapped points - you can compute a transformation and transform all points. if you only need translation - what does the mapped points has to do with it?

Comment: That is what I want to do. But to find this transformation I want to do what I've written in my question. And some more stuff like relaxation of all the points and for that I have to approximate the shortest path on a 3D surface... but that's sth I plan to do on my own